# How to get iOS to run a sub process?

Tags: php, ios, ipad

I am writing an app for iOS that will start the php binary as a sub process.

The following code is used:

```
NSString * command = @"/bin/sh -c '";
command = [command stringByAppendingString:[BibleditPaths php]];
command = [command stringByAppendingString:@" -v' > /tmp/php.txt 2>&1"];
int output = system ([command UTF8String]);
NSString* msg = [@(output) stringValue];
NSLog(msg, @"");
```

The php binary can be started on a jailbroken iPad from the command line. This is the output:

```
PHP 5.4.31 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2014 11:06:21) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

When starting the php binary from the code above, iOS sends the SIGKILL signal.
The php binary does not run or produce any output.

/bin/sh produces this output:

```
sh: line 1:  2806 Killed: 9               /bin/sh -c '/var/mobile/Applications/DFE552CC-ECBE-4A73-82CF-24870E5D9F62/Library/usr/local/bin/php -v' > /tmp/php.txt 2>&1
2014-09-15 17:33:41.676 PHPRunner[2804:60b] 35072
```

What can I do to get iOS to run this process successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was posted on the Apple iOS development forum (https://devforums.apple.com/index.jspa).

The response there was:

"None of that is supported (or permitted by the application sandbox) on iOS."

Subsequently the question was deleted from the forum.

I am posting the answer here so the information is kept for the public.